# How to use 'script/install' on mysql

Tags: mysql, insoshi

I'm trying to install insoshi on linux OS, and I am having trouble with a certain part. I have copied the database, but I am not sure how to configure the database.yml file with my password. Also, the installation instructions require me to use this command within mysql:

```
$ script/install
```

I am also gaining an error involving the rake file:

```
LoadError: cannot load such file -- rake/rdoctask
/home/james/insoshi/Rakefile:8:in `<top (required)>'
```

How do I install the insoshi social networking platform with this step?

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure how to configure the database.yml file with my password

Open up `config/database.yml` file and edit a line that starts with `password:`. Put your database password there.

```
password: my_db_password
```

> `$ script/install`

As you can see from the github repo, it is a [simple ruby file](https://github.com/insoshi/insoshi/blob/master/script/install). So, you may decide to run it using `ruby script/install` command or simply copy-paste it to your command line and hit enter.

Comment: I am not sure how or where to type this command. Do I open the mysql space on the command line, or do I enter this directly in the command line for linux.

Comment: For some reason this does nothing. It doesn't recognize the command. Is there something missing.

Comment: Just run `ruby script/install` instead.

Comment: I did. This is the command that is not having any action. Is there something missing from the ruby library that would do this? The system doesn't recognize the command.

Comment: What is the error message? Add it to your original question.

Comment: I've posted the error message. Can you tell me how to install it?

Comment: Have you installed all dependencies with `bundle install`?